# How to expire a session if user leave an interface for 2 minutes? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

when user log in to application and leave that application for 2 minutes or don't access that within 2 minutes than :
**How to expire his session or how to log out him?**

Comment: Set your session time to 2 minutes.

Comment: @Nico i did that but that logout user even if he is using interface

Comment: The web is stateless... This means that as soon as the request \ response is finished your session timer count down starts. The only way to actually continually check if they are online is some sort of pulse check ajax method from the client to the server every x seconds \ minutes to keep their session alive.

Comment: @Nico how to do this can you share any example please

Comment: @Nico sorry there was some problem with my internet:( please reply my comment i have posted below your provide ansewer pleaseeeee

Comment: i have edited my answer (sorry I had to sleep at some point)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example of javascript that sends a request to the page /myKeepAliveUrl every 15 seconds.

```
var timer = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
    timer = setTimeout(keepAlive, 15000);
});

function keepAlive(){
    $.get('/myKeepAliveUrl', null, function () {
        timer = setTimeout(keepAlive, 15000);
    });

}
```

Now you must create a page for the keep alive ping (call it what ever you like) and this page \ action \ handler doesn't need to do anything as its only job is to keep the users session alive.

Place this code in a common JavaScript file and include it in your master page (aspx), layout (mvc) etc.

**Edit: Addition response.**

From the comments recieved I would like to add a simple how to example with explanation.

Firstly, all you want to do is keep the users `Server` session alive. Now the session timer starts its 'count down' as soon as the last recieved `Request` has been completed (`Response` completed). Now this may be in the form of regular web browsing, ajax requests etc.

Now as we are only insterested in keeping the session alive through aJax we just need a simple handler that returns a Http Response of `200` 'OK'.

Now using web forms this is entirly possible using a `ASPX` page. However an `ASPX` page is designed to return HTML content to the response. As we are dealing with a simple request that has no response using the `ASPX` page will work, but is not ideal.

My suggestion would be to use a `GenericHandler` `.ASHX` item. A generic Handler is a basic Http handler that responds to Http Requests. This handler can respond with any MIME type and data so is perfectly suited for the job.

To add the `GenericHandler` add a new item and search for `GenericHandler`
[image]

Now a `GenericHandler` out of the box doesn't access session data. To enable session data for the generic handler you must inherit from the interface `System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState` such as.

```
public class myKeepAliveUrl : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState 
{
}
```

Now the basic handler is setup and has access to the session data. The next step is to add some session logic and return a valid response. The final class is as basic as.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class myKeepAliveUrl : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Session != null)
            context.Session["_reloadKey"] = Guid.NewGuid(); //do something with the session (not really needed)
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.Response.Write("OK"); //write OK.. Not really needed
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

}
```

Now to call your generic handler you simply use the URL.

```
/myKeepAliveUrl.ashx
```

**EDIT 2: More help.**

OK from your comment it also appears that you not only want to keep the session alive you also want to detect if there has been no activity on the page for 2 minutes. Now this can be done a number of ways. What I would suggest is hooking into two main events through jQuery at the document level.

These events `keyup()` and `mousemove()` will provide you with the ability to monitor the user navigating the page. Now we are using both `keyup` and `mousemove` as I could navigate via keyboard, or via the mouse. I also may spend more than two minutes filling in a web-form using <kbd>Tab</kbd> instead of using my mouse.

Ok some code. This is pretty straight forward but we will use both the previous example and this example in tandem. ( I have commented the code)

```
//our keep alive timer
var keepAliveTimer = null,
    //our last activity timer
    lastActivityTimer = null,
    //refresh time in milliseconds
    refreshTime = 15000,
    //logout timer in milliseconds
    logoutTime = 120000; //120000 = 2 mins in milliseconds


//document ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    //set the keep alive timer. This timer fires every 15 seconds to keep our session alive
    keepAliveTimer = setTimeout(keepAlive, refreshTime);
    //monitor document events for key up & mouse move
    $(document).keyup(restartSession).mousemove(restartSession);
    //start the last activity timer
    lastActivityTimer = setTimeout(forceLogout, logoutTime);
});

//restart session timer.
function restartSession(e) {
    //clear the timer if set
    if (lastActivityTimer != null)
        clearTimeout(lastActivityTimer);
    //log to console 
    console.log('restarting activity timer'); //<-- REMOVE ME IN PRODUCTION
    //reset the timer to 2 minutes
    lastActivityTimer = setTimeout(forceLogout, logoutTime); //120000 = 2 mins in milliseconds
}

//function fired when no activity has been  recieved for two mins
function forceLogout() {
    //notify user of logout
    alert('You failed to do any activity for 2 minutes. Please re-login');
    //direct user to logout page. Must be logout (or a page that logs the user out) as the keep alive timer is designed to keep the user logged in.
    window.location.href = "/logout.aspx";
}

//keep alive function to keep the user logged in.
function keepAlive() {
    $.get('/myKeepAliveUrl.ashx', null, function () {
        timer = setTimeout(keepAlive, refreshTime);
    });
}
```

Now there is a real problem with this whole concept. In this example you are firing an event in javascript everytime the mouse moves and every time a key is pressed. Thus thousands of events will fire. Luckily our code is quite simple, however this could be disasterous if you start trying to fire ajax requests on these events.

Now some notes about what we are doing.

1. In the design we would like the user session time to be 2 minutes. Therefore as many users may spend more than two minutes on a page we need the ability to 'keep the session alive' thus we have the `keepAlive()` system. This system sends a request from the client every 15 seconds (or configured interval) via aJax. This ajax request simply modifies a session variable and responds `HTTP:200 - OK` back to the client.
2. In addition to keeping the session alive, we also want to know when the client is 'idle' for 2 minutes or more. In the event this does happend we need to alert the client they have been idle for two minutes and then direct them to the login page to re-login. Now this system monitors the users activity on the page by hooking into the `mousemove` and `keyup` events from the document. Every time these events are intercepted we restart the user activity monitor. Now if the user fails to perform any events for 2 minutes the user recieves an `alert` stating they must relogin. **IMPORTANT** as step 1. is designed to keep the session alive the user's session will be active and alive. Thus the user login cookie is still active. From here you **MUST** direct them to a page that will **log them out** and then re-direct them to a login page.

Using the methods listed above you should be able to write a complete solution for your problem.  Hope this helps.

Comment: where to save this `page /myKeepAliveUrl`

Comment: You create whatever page you want and call it whatever you like. This page (handler) simply keeps the session alive.

Comment: i want my products page to be alive so can i write like  `$.get('~/Products.aspx', null . . . `

Comment: Yeah that would work. My recommendation is to create a blank page though. Your products page probably lists a load of products and runs long methods. As the purpose of this page is to simply keep the session alive I would do a basic page. I will update the answer with a much more applicable way of doing this.

Comment: Hi thank's  @Nico -- i used same same thing i left my page for 8 minutes but that doesn't show me any notification. Secondly i want to move to login page in case user don't use application with in 2 minutes

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the user is still responding you will have to put up a timer that fires after 2 minutes and redirects to the logout page. When the user moves his mouse in the browser reset the timer. It's like a screensaver.

Comment: how to do this can you share any example please

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, you can set the session timeout as described in this post:

http://justgeeks.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/aspnet-session-timeouts.html

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="20" /> 
<system.web>
```

Comment: i did that but that logout user even if he is using interface

Comment: Well no it won't because HTTP is stateless.

Comment: interface usage is not taken into consideration if it doesn't make any postbacks or page loads