# How to check if the mouse did not move for 2 minutes in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to know if the mouse did not move for two minutes, If so a log out will occur automatically.
Plz help.

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: Please check these questions this will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983375/how-to-expire-a-session-if-user-leave-an-interface-for-2-minutes-asp-net
OR
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603374/how-can-i-trigger-an-auto-logout-within-a-windows-forms-application

Comment: Use a timer that gets reset every time the mouse move event is triggered. Or look in to handling window messages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add a timer control to your application.
2. Subscribe to mouseover and keydown events - when they fire, reset the timer.
3. When the timer fires (ie mouse hasn't moved and key's haven't been pressed for x amount of time), lock the screen / prompt for login.

This could also help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13756/Detecting-Application-Idleness